# Querying SQL data using three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve the CategoryID and CategoryName by seeing the CategoryBusinessMapping and Review Rating table. I am trying to retrieve the data of following **Category** table:

```
Category     ParentCategoryID     CategoryName
1            null                 Education
2            1                    School
3            null                 Health
4            3                    Doctors
5            1                    Colleges
```

I have the **Business** table which has BusinessID and BusinessName and BusinessDescription like this:

```
BusinessID     BusinessName     BusinessDescription
YP00001        XYZ              ABCD
YP00002        ABC              XYZA
```

I have the **CategoryBusinessMapping** table like this:

```
MappingID     CategoryID     BusinessID
1             1              YP00001
2             2              YP00001
3             5              YP00001
4             3              YP00002
5             4              YP00002
```

I have this mapping table to map the different Category with the Business. I also have the **Rating** table like this:

```
RatingID     BusinessID
1            YP00001
2            YP00001
3            YP00001
4            YP00002
5            YP00002
```

Here in this table I am assuming that a record having same BusinessID is fall under most popular Business. Meaning, here in above the Business ABCD having ID = YP00001 has four records in Rating table. Therefore it falls under most popular Business. Similarly YP00002 falls next to YP00001. By seeing the most popular Business in descending order I want to retrieve CategoryName and CategoryID. I have tried this to retrieve from the Rating table only:

```
select   Distinct ReviewRating.BusinessID
         ,Count(*)as Rating
from     YP.utblYPReviewRatingDtls as ReviewRating
group by ReviewRating.BusinessID 
order by Rating desc
```

I have tried this:

```
  SELECT  distinct c.CategoryName, b.BusinessID
    FROM Category c
     INNER JOIN categoryBusinessMapping  cbm
     ON (c.CategoryID=cbm.CategoryID)
     INNER JOIN Business b 
    ON (cbm.BusinessID=b.BusinessID)
     LEFT JOIN Rating  r 
     ON (cbm.BusinessID=r.BusinessID)
     where c.ParentCategoryID is null
```

but I get the result which is redundant. I also remove the BusinessID from the query and I get the result but the result is incorrect. How can I remove redundancy and also get the proper output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` and take the count of  `BusinessID` from rating table and order your results

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(r.BusinessID) AS bcount FROM Category  c
INNER JOIN CategoryBusinessMapping  cbm ON (c.Category=cbm.CategoryID)
INNER JOIN Business b ON (cbm.BusinessID=b.BusinessID)
LEFT JOIN Rating  r ON (cbm.BusinessID=r.BusinessID)
GROUP BY r.BusinessID
ORDER BY bcount DESC
```